# 1 and 2 and ((3 AND 4) or 5 or (6 and 7)) Can any one help writing logic to expand expression and list out all possible expressions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1 and 2 and ((3 AND 4) or 5 or (6 and 7)) Can any one help writing logic to expand expression and list out all possible expressions?

Eg.,
Result:

- 1 and 2 and 3 and 4
- 1 and 2 and 5
- 1 and 2 and 6 and 7

Comment: So you really have a logical expression like `A & B & ((C & D) | E | (F & G))` and you're looking for all possible values of `A` through `G` that will make the expression true?

Comment: Further to @mu's comment, you need to (edit to) clarify your question. If the statement of the question I gave in my answer is correct you can use that or some variant of it. Also, you need to change `AND` to `and`.

Comment: I am looking for a way to expand a logical expression (in a string) of the form: '(A or B) and ((C and D) or E)' in ruby to produce a list of all positive sets, i.e. ['A and C and D', 'A and E', 'B and C and D', 'B and E'] eg2: A and B and ((C and D) or E or (F and G)) in ruby to produce a list of all positive sets, i.e. ['A and B and C and D', 'A and B and E', 'A and B and F and G' ] but I have been unable to find how to do this. Any help, or a reference to a resource that might help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, do not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. That is very rude towards the people who put in the hard work, usually in their free time, usually without getting paid, to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted the question as follows. Suppose `x1`, `x2`,..., `x7` are seven variables, each having a value of `true` or `false`. List the combinations of values of variables that result in

```
x1 and x2 and ((x3 and x4) or x5 or (x6 and x7))
```

evaluating `true`.

We can obtain the desired results as follows.

```
arr = [true, false].repeated_permutation(7).
  select {|x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7| x1 and x2 and ((x3 and x4) or x5 or (x6 and x7))}
  #=> [[true, true, true, true, true, true, true],
  #    [true, true, true, true, true, true, false]] 
  #    ...
  #    [true, true, false, false, false, true, true]]
```

See [Array#repeated_permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation).

To make the results easier to visualize we can display a table that shows which variables are `true` for each of the 23 elements of `arr`:

```
puts "x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7"
puts "--------------------"
arr.each { |a| puts a.map { |tf| tf ? "X  " : "   " }.join }
```

displays

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
--------------------
X  X  X  X  X  X  X  
X  X  X  X  X  X     
X  X  X  X  X     X  
X  X  X  X  X        
X  X  X  X     X  X  
X  X  X  X     X     
X  X  X  X        X  
X  X  X  X           
X  X  X     X  X  X  
X  X  X     X  X     
X  X  X     X     X  
X  X  X     X        
X  X  X        X  X  
X  X     X  X  X  X  
X  X     X  X  X     
X  X     X  X     X  
X  X     X  X        
X  X     X     X  X  
X  X        X  X  X  
X  X        X  X     
X  X        X     X  
X  X        X        
X  X           X  X
```

Note that `x1` and `x2` both evaluate `true` for each element of `arr`. Also, there are `2**4 #=> 16` combinations for which `x5` is `true`, as `x3`, `x4`, `x6` and `x7` can each be either `true` or `false` when `x5` is `true`.

Comment: 1 is  name equals G1, 
2 is type equals category, 
3 is state includes S1
4 is city includes C1, C2 
5 is Sate includes S4, S5
6 is State includes S6
7 is city include C3, C4

Possible values for the expression 1 and 2 and ((3 AND 4) or 5 or (6 and 7)) with above values


G1, category, S1, C1
G1,category, S1, C2
G1,category, S2, C1
G1,category, S4
G1,category, S5
G1,category, S6, C3
G1,category, S6, C4

Comment: At the time of writing there are two votes to close your question. Readers have voted to close because your question is not clear. @muistooshort asked for clarification. I asked for clarification. If you do not clarify your question (by editing it) it undoubtedly will be closed. Your comment above does not help me understand what you are trying to do. And why do you keep referring to `AND`? Ruby does not have a keyword `AND` (but it does have a keyword `and`).

Comment: I am looking for a way to expand a logical expression (in a string) of the form:

'(A or B) and ((C and D) or E)'

in ruby to produce a list of all positive sets, i.e.

['A and C and D',
'A and E',
'B and C and D',
'B and E']


eg2: A and B and ((C and D) or E or (F and G))
in ruby to produce a list of all positive sets, i.e.

['A and B and C and D',
'A and B and E',
'A and B and F and G'
]

but I have been unable to find how to do this. Any help, or a reference to a resource that might help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Since all expressions are literals, there are no possible different results, and this expression will always evaluate to `4`:

```ruby
1 and 2 and ((3 and 4) or 5 or (6 and 7))
1 and 2 and (       4  or 5 or (6 and 7))
1 and 2 and (       4  or 5 or        7 )
1 and 2 and         4  or 5 or        7
      2 and         4  or 5 or        7
                    4  or 5 or        7
                    4       or        7
                    4
```

Comment: Actully i need logic for possible paths from this expression below are possible expansions . Like distribute law expansion.. a) 1 and 2 and 3 and 4
b) 1 and 2 and 5
c) 1 and 2 and 6 and 7

Comment: There is only one possible result.

Comment: I am looking for a way to expand a logical expression (in a string) of the form: '(A or B) and ((C and D) or E)' in ruby to produce a list of all positive sets, i.e. ['A and C and D', 'A and E', 'B and C and D', 'B and E'] eg2: A and B and ((C and D) or E or (F and G)) in ruby to produce a list of all positive sets, i.e. ['A and B and C and D', 'A and B and E', 'A and B and F and G' ] but I have been unable to find how to do this. Any help, or a reference to a resource that might help would be greatly appreciated.